# NHibernate 3.0: No FirstOrDefault() with QueryOver?

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, queryover

I am playing with FluentNHibernate and NH 3.0, using the LINQ provider and the new QueryOver syntax.

Now with QueryOver I want to get an item (called result) with a timestamp value as close as possible to a given value, but not greater:

```
 Result precedingOrMatchingResult = Session.QueryOver<Result>().
        Where(r => r.TimeStamp < timeStamp).
        OrderBy(r => r.TimeStamp).Desc.                
        FirstOrDefault(); //get the preceding or matching result, if there is any
```

Now, Intellisense tells me that there is no such thing as a `FirstOrDefault()` method. I could, of course, enumerate my ordered query, and then use LINQ to get my item. But this would load all items into memory first.

**Is there an alternative to `FirstOrDefault()`, or have I understood something completely wrong?**

Comment: Look for `SingleOrDefault()`. Please accept @RRR 's answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

NH 3 has an integrated LINQ provider (queries are translated internally to HQL/SQL). You have to add the NHibernate.Linq namespace and then:

```
Result precedingOrMatchingResult = Session.Query<Result>().
    Where(r => r.TimeStamp < timeStamp).
    OrderByDescending(r => r.TimeStamp).
    FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Looks great, I'll give it a try (only next year however, since I am off now!)

Comment: This does the trick. However, since in my Where clauses, there are some additional restrictions, I found that LINQ to NH does not Support the .HasValue() method support for Nullable types. Too bad, but I now check for != null which works.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of doing this with QueryOver<T>.  The answer is valid just not for the question asked. @RRR's is more correct.

Answer (score 40):

I have now found out that I could use the Take() extension method on the IQueryOver instance, and only the enumerate to a list, like so:

```
Result precedingOrMatchingResult = Session.QueryOver<Result>().
        Where(r => r.TimeStamp < timeStamp).
        OrderBy(r => r.TimeStamp).Desc.   
        Take(1).List(). //enumerate only on element of the sequence!
        FirstOrDefault(); //get the preceding or matching result, if there is any
```

Comment: Yup.  `Take` is what I was going to recommend.  Combine that with RRR's `SingleOrDefault` instead of `List().FirstOrDefault()` and it's perfect.

Comment: Actually `.Take(1)` will do the same thing as `.SetFetchSize(1)` in the sense that it will tell SQL that you only want one result. In both cases you are not executing a query for all matching results and then enumerating over the first one.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that there is a typo in the comment. 'enumerate only on' -> 'enumerate only one'. Good answer.

Answer (score 23):

```
Result precedingOrMatchingResult = Session.QueryOver<Result>()
                                          .Where(r => r.TimeStamp < timeStamp)
                                          .OrderBy(r => r.TimeStamp).Desc
                                          .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Causes NHibernate.NonUniqueResultException

Comment: Try `.Take(1)` before `.SingleOrDefault()` in that case. See @Marcel's answer.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. SingleOrDefault throws an exception if there are more than one results. FirstOrDefault does not. You could however try .Take(1).SingleOrDefault()

Comment: @wezzix it's a good point, but the OP expressed no need for the exceptional behavior - looks like he didn't know or care about it - he just asked for a one-call alternative to enumerating everything and taking the 1st

Comment: @PandaWood no, OP is sorting and want the top result, thus SingleOrDefault does not answer the question (on its own).

Answer (score 10):

Try

```
Result precedingOrMatchingResult = Session.QueryOver<Result>().
        Where(r => r.TimeStamp < timeStamp).
        OrderBy(r => r.TimeStamp).Desc.
        SetFetchSize(1).
        UniqueResult();
```

UniqueResult will return a single value, or null if no value is found, which is kinda what First or Default does.

Setting the Fetch Size to 1 may or may not be required, I'd test that with a profiler.

Comment: I had a look into it. UniqueResult seems to be similar to SingleOrDefault, but I do not have a single item. I have a list, and I want to pick the first item only.

Comment: What you want your query to return is the first item only, right? Why return a list from the database server and then throw away most of the work?

Answer (score 0):

`SetFetchSize(1)` is required. If your LINQ query returns more than one result, it will throw an NHibernate exception using `UniqueResult()`, as it is only expecting one result to be returned from the query.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for your contribution! Your answer seems not being 100% related to the question as `SetFetchSize` was not mentioned in the question. Perhaps you can explain more clearly or correct. Our guide [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) might give you useful hints. Thanks!

Comment: Hi David, I meant to comment on the answer above me, not provide a whole new answer. My mistake.